# Degeneracy of orbitals?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, orbitals, atoms

Why is that in an external magnetic field(uniform) the degeneracy of d,f orbitals is lost but the degeneracy of p orbitals remain intact if the main cause of losing degeneracy is the difference in energy of differently oriented orbitals in the magnetic field?

Comment: Do you have a source stating the degeneracy of p orbitals in the presence of an external magnetic field?

Answer (score 1):

My textbook states that the energy of the p orbitals *will* split in a magnetic field. (Physical Chemistry, McQuarrie, p.210)

Comment: On a sidenote, do you recommend that book? I've been looking at it.

Comment: I do like this textbook - it's fairly straightforward and not too bad to understand. However, I haven't used other pchem textbooks in depth, so I'm not sure if this is the best out there. Heard the Levine text was good as well.

Comment: I used to teach from McQuarrie, it was heavy! but definitely the best out there.

Answer (score 0):

Any energy that belong to orbitals with non-zero angular moment (ie. anything, except s orbitals) will split in magnetic field.

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Comment: Check the Zeeman-effect (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeeman_effect) in your preferred textbook. It describes how magnetic field interacts with atoms (molecules etc). The electronic part of it generally can be factored to an angular and a spin contribution. Sometimes they are strongly couples (e.g. lanthanides) and it doesn't work, but at basic level we don't care about those cases. From that it comes that angular contribution exist always when there is a non-zero angular moment.